Big O notation problem (dividing two big o notations)
As in topic I got problem with understanding exercise.
Task is to check if this is true or false. For me it's true, but
my teacher said that this is false but I don't know why. Can anyone explain it to me why this is false?
and whole task is like:
Check if the following statement is true (prove or provide a counterexample):
$g_n$ can't be $0$ for $n$ that is big enough (bcs we can't divide by $0$ I guess) and:
if $$f_n=O(n^6)$$
and if $$g_n=O(n^2)$$
then
$$\frac{f_n}{g_n}=O(n^4)$$
my answer

Post edit:  Maybe you've excluded $g_n=0$, but you didn't exclude $g_n\to 0$.  Say $g_n=2^{-n}$ for instance.

your gn=2^-n doesn't override somehow O(n^2)

$g_n = O(n^2)$ does NOT implies $\frac{1}{g_n} = O(\frac{1}{n^2}$. Or in terms of inequalities: $|g_n| \le D n^2$ does NOT implies $|\frac{1}{g_n}| \le \frac{1}{D n^2}$.

Of course $2^{-n}=O(n^2)$.  Big$-O$ is very weak, all we know is that $g_n<Cn^2$ for some constant $C$ and $n$ large.  But with $2^{-n}$ this holds for $C=1$.

So if i'm wrong, (well it is clear now where is problem) how to do it in correct way? I don't know any method to "divide" two big O notations.

The statement is false. You can't divide two big $O$ functions.

So the correct way is to say: The statement is false, here's a counterexample: ...

Okay, thanks for helping guys.
